# Using Android Oreo API in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-8.0-oreo, text-justify

Android Oreo introduces text justification in Text View.

I created a custom renderer for Label and add the following in Visual Studio 15.6.6.

```
    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
      textview.SetJustificationMode(JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);
    }
```

However, VS says Text View does not contain a definition for SetJustificationMode.

I have installed Android 8.0 (API26) and Android 8.1 (API27) SDK.

Any assistance is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you also set the target framework to the right API version that supports this? You can do so in you project properties of the Droid project

Comment: Yes. Under Application, Compile using Android Version (Target Framework) is Android 8.1 (API27).  Under Android Manifest, Minimum Android Version is Android 5.1 (API22) and Target Android Version is Android 8.1 (API27).

Answer (score 0):

The method `setProperty(...)` may be mapped to the property `Property` in [Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android).

Example:

```
TextView textview = new TextView(Context);

if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
{
  textview.JustificationMode = Android.Text.JustificationMode.InterWord;
}
```

Using Visual Studio, the metadata of `TextView` can be accessed with "*Go To Definition (F12)*".

Example:

> ...
>
> public class TextView : View, ViewTreeObserver.IOnPreDrawListener, IJavaObject, IDisposable
>
> ...
>
> public virtual JustificationMode JustificationMode { get; set; }
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes, I managed to set JustificationMode to InterWord now.  However, the text display is still not full justification. (It looks different compared to without JustificationMode.InterWord but it is not full justification.)